Eyes deforming? Warping when I move the eye tracker control
I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why my character's eyes are doing what their doing when I move the eye tracker controller.
Do they need to be parented or something? If someone could dumb it down for me as I'm still new  to blender and this is my first ever character model/rig.

Thanks in advance! :)


Yes. Each eye needs to be a separate object with Scale and Rotation applied (Ctrl-A > Scale & Rotation in Object mode) before you rig your model.

Okay. I went back to separate the eyes before I generated the Rig. And applied Scale & Rotation. However, I still getting the same issue?

please provide blend file, because rigging is quite complex and you didn't show us any technical settings you made for that rig. thx.

As @Chris says we'll need to see your Blend file but I'm guessing that you may not have reset the origins of each eye after you seperated them so they're still rotating around the same origin.  Select each eye in turn then on the right-click menu choose set Origin > Origin to Geometry.  You can your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Okay. I uploaded my blender file to the question.
Thanks again, I appreciate the help.

I think I'll let @Chris answer that as he's much more familiar with rigging than I am. Although it is disabled in the viewport, I see that you still have another 'eyes' object there with a mirror and armature modifier on it. I don't know whether that's confusing rig generation?

Do you have any eye bones? If no, I think that is your problem. Create a bone that starts in the back of the eye and ends in the end.
Parent each eye to its respective bone, then add the Damped Track constraints to each, and select the target to each respective tracker to each side.

I do have eye bones and they are parented to the head bone.  I'm attempting to try your advice and so I added the damped track constraints to each eye, but I'm a little confused on what I need to select for the target for each?
I'm still quite new to blender, so I apologize for my lack of knowledge and understanding.
I appreciate the help :)

your tracker has 2 circles in it, ritgh? Those are the individual eyes tracker, when adding the damped track modefier , you must add the targer to the individual eye tracker. I can see you are using riggify, if you ALREDY have the bone, I think you dont need to add the constraint, it is alredy in there.
What you need to do is to delet all vertex grups, delet the armature modefier, select the eye bone, (be sure your rig is in rest mode for this step), then parent the eye to the eye bone (bone parent)

Oh my gosh! It worked! - Well for the one eye the other eye isn't moving now....

Actually not only is the one eye not moving with the tracker, but now the rest of the rig is detached from the rest of the body. The rig only controls the eyes, teeth and tongue.
